# Should properties with space be quoted in CSS

Tags: css

I am learning HTML and CSS from W3schools. I came across a confusing instruction. [HTML5 Style Guide of W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_syntax.asp) says "Only use quotes around values if the value contains spaces" in the Style sheets section. And it gave an example that looks like this:

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16em;
  color: black;
}
```

Where the font-family property has a quoted value of Arial Black. But when I was doing the [W3schools CSS background Exercise](https://www.w3schools.com/css/exercise.asp?filename=exercise_background4), the following code doesn't place the background image at the right top position

```html
<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-image: url("img_tree.png");
      background-position: "right top";
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

After I removed the quotes around "right top", the background image was placed at the right top position.
After some research, I read from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601588/can-css-property-values-be-quoted) that CSS properties generally cannot be quoted.

Now I am confused. From the W3schools style guide, it seems that it is a recommended standard to quote CSS properties with spaces. But then it doesn't work! When must I quote and when should I quote (in terms of the recommended standard)?

Comment: I think you are correct to be dubious of this supposed rule of "Only use quotes around values if the value contains spaces".  I can definitely think of scenarios in CSS where quotes are called for and spaces don't exist, as well scenarios in which you wouldn't and _couldn't_ use quotes despite the presence of spaces.  My best recommendation: take this cheat sheet with a few grains of salt.  When in doubt for a specific CSS property and how it should be formed, I'd recommend searching on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/) for the correct syntax.

Comment: I'd recommend taking *anything* on W3schools with a few grains of salt. It's notoriously not-entirely-reliable. MDN is definitely a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

> When must I quote and when should I quote (in terms of the recommended standard)?

There is no standard and no recommendation. Each propery has its own syntax that you need to follow. As simple as that.

For `background-position` and as defined [in the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#background-position)<sup>1</sup>:

```
<bg-position> =  [ left | center | right | top | bottom | <length-percentage> ]
|
  [ left | center | right | <length-percentage> ]
  [ top | center | bottom | <length-percentage> ]
|
  [ center | [ left | right ] <length-percentage>? ] &&
  [ center | [ top | bottom ] <length-percentage>? ]
```

You can follow the syntax to understand the meaning of `|`, `&&`, etc and you will see that `<string>` (quoted value) is not allowed as value of `background-position`

Related: [Why are CSS named grid areas not in quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60026586/8620333)

---

You should also note that some properties are called shorthand so they can accept **multiple** values and the should never be quoted.

Trivial examples:

```
border:2px solid red;
padding: 20px 10px;
margin:0 auto;
background:url(...) top/cover no-repeat fixed;
```

Again, the syntax of each property is clearly defined and you simply need to follow it without much thinking.

---

<sup>1</sup> It can be hard to navigate and search the official specification so I recommend using [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) to find the property and its syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Do not confuse font-family property with other properties

We can add and use any new custom font-family with our own custom name!

Some css properties required to be quoted
some predefined values need not to be quoted in CSS